# Why do some say that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

A continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is one which satisfies the following property: for every open set $U\subset Y$, the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

I don't see why according to this definition $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous at $0$. The inverse image of every open set of the form $(a,\infty)$ is open, it is $(0,\frac{1}{a})$. Similarly, the inverse image of $(-\infty,-a)$ is $(-\frac{1}{a},0)$.
And one can see that the inverses of other forms of open sets are also clearly open.

Why then is $1/x$ discontinuous according to some?

Comment: it's not defined at $0$. In order to be able to talk about (dis) continuity in a point, you first need to define it there.

Comment: It *is* continuous on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ and at $x=0$ it is undefined. Every value which you give it at $0$ to make it a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ yields a discontinuous function.

Comment: So shouldn't we say "$1/x$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and not defined at $x=0$, instead of saying it is discontinuous at $0$?

Comment: It might be meant, that there is no continuous extension of $f$ to whole $\mathbb{R}$. - But in rigurous notation you'd be right.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I explain it in my calculus class. There are three slightly different ways to talk about continuity.

1. A function $f$ is continuous at $c$ if $f(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$, with some one-side limits allowed at the endpoint of a domain. I.e. a function is discontinuous at a point if the function is not defined there or the value does not equal the limit. Thus, $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is discontinuous at zero.
2. A function is continuous in an interval if it is continuous at every point in that interval. Thus, $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is continuous in any interval that does not contain zero and is not continuous in any interval containing zero.
3. A function is continuous if it is continuous at every point in its domain. Thus, $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is a continuous function.

Unfortunately, not everyone is consistent in terminology. But I seem to agree with the sources you reference.

Comment: But if we're strictly speaking about the formal definition of continuity (or discontinuity; I'm talking about $\epsilon- \delta$), then it's inconsistent with this definition to say $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous or discontinuous at $0$.  The point is not in its domain, so we can't determine one way or another.

Comment: @user46944: Of course we can talk about it. My particular formal definition of continuity says that if a function is not defined at a particular value then it is not continuous there. So we can determine continuity for any point, whether or not it is in the function's domain. Do you have some good reason to disallow my definition? I use the definition given in *Calculus: Graphical, Numerical, Agebraic* by Finney et al., page 75.

Comment: Another example: $\tan{x}$.  I used to tell people this function is discontinuous at the points where it is undefined.  But actually, that's not true.  We can't say one way or another because the definition doesn't apply to these points.  So we say $\tan{x}$ is continuous because it's continuous on its domain.

Comment: @user46944: My definition, which has good support, says that $\tan x$ is a continuous function, and it also says that it is discontinuous at $\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$. That is perfectly consistent, if you pay careful attention to the wording.

Comment: Well, let's see: We say $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = c$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c) | < \epsilon$.  Then a function is discontinuous at $x = c$ if it is *not continuous* there.  Which means we have to logically negate this definition.  The logical negation is: there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there is $x$ with $|x - c|< \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon$.  As you can see, this logical negation of continuity also uses $f(c)$.  If $f$ is not defined at $c$, the def doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user46944: No, *we* do not say that. *I with others* say that you should add to your definition "...if $c$ is in the domain of $f$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$..." A function is discontinuous at $x=c$ if it is not continuous there. Where is the inconsistency?

Comment: The inconsistency is in generally saying $f$ is a continuous function.  If we say $f$ is a continuous function, then at each point we check, it should be continuous.  But we only say it is continuous if it is continuous everywhere on its domain.  I think it would be very confusing to suddenly say $f$ is a continuous function.  But wait, it's discontinuous at this point that it's not defined on.  But otherwise, it's continuous.  It would make discussing the continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ as a real valued function confusing.  If we just say this is "continuous", then we expect it to be cts everywhere.

Comment: But under your definition, $\sqrt{x}$ as a real valued function is discontinuous at just as many points as it is continuous at.  So can we really call it a continuous function under this definition?

Comment: @user46944: Yes, I can really call $\sqrt x$ a continuous function, since it is continuous at every point in its domain. You may not like these definitions, but they are consistent with each other (if not with yours), are accepted by many others, and work for my students. Have a good night, I am going to bed now.

Answer (score 8):

Part of the challenge is that calculus, arguably more than many other areas of contemporary mathematics, is heavily influenced by classical terminology and methods.

The concept of "function", which is taken somewhat for granted today, developed over a long period of time, and for much of that time the notion was much more broad than the present one. See Wikipedia's article "[History of the function concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept)".  Quoting from that article about Hardy's famous book *A Course in Pure Mathematics*:

> Hardy 1908, pp. 26–28 defined a function as a relation between two variables $x$ and $y$ such that "to some values of $x$ at any rate correspond values of $y$." He neither required the function to be defined for all values of x nor to associate each value of $x$ to a single value of $y$. This broad definition of a function encompasses more relations than are ordinarily considered functions in contemporary mathematics. For example, Hardy's definition includes multivalued functions and what in computability theory are called partial functions.

This kind of definition was not unique to Hardy; he was no doubt presenting mathematics as many at the turn of the 20th century understood it, and nobody can doubt Hardy's mathematical acumen.

From a viewpoint like the one he expressed, it makes perfect sense to have $1/x$ be both undefined and discontinuous at $x = 0$.  And that is the way the language is often used in calculus today.

In the 19th and 20th centiries, the notion of functions changed from a viewpoint that thought of functions primarily as expressions, to a viewpoint that also incorporated functions defined by series, and onward to the modern viewpoint where a function need not have any defining "rule".  By its nature, calculus is more attuned to functions that are defined by formulas or series, and as such the terminology has maintained some of the traditional character from a time when the concepts of formula and function were conflated.

On a related note, some mathematicians today define a function to be continuous *at a limit point of the domain* if the function can be extended to the limit point in a way that makes it continuous in the sense quoted above. So these mathematicians would say that $(1-x)/(1-x)$ defines a continuous function, because the function can be defined at $x = 1$ in a way to make it continuous.  These mathematicians would also say $1/x$ is discountinuous at $x = 0$, because it cannot be extended to $x = 0$ in a continuous manner.

The main conclusion to take here is to remember that the terminology of calculus is not as standardized as the terminology of more advanced mathematics (and even that is not as standardized as you might suspect).  And the terminology of calculus is more influenced by traditional viewpoints on functions. So, although calculus *can be* formalized in the style of real analysis, the definitions actually used in a calculus course may not match the ones that would be used in a course on analysis.

P.S. Another interesting example of "traditional terminology" in calculus relates to "indeterminate forms".

Answer (score 6):

For what's worth, I checked two french books and Rudin's PMA, and in all cases, discontinuity is only defined for a point of the domain of definition of the function. As the other answers suggest, there may be other definitions of "discontinuity", for points where $f$ is not defined. I would say it's relatively harmless, apart from introducing misleading terminology.

---

It's misleading for another reason than just terminology, I think. A function is defined to be given by a set of "inputs", a set of "outputs", and a relation such that **each** input has an output. It makes little sense to tell anything about (continuity of) a function where it's not defined, in some sense it doesn't even "belong" to the function.

For example, $f:x\rightarrow 1/x$ is defined on $]-\infty,0[\;\cup\;]0,+\infty[$. I could tell it's discontinuous at $0$. But then I could also tell it's discontinuous at $(1,2)$ (where this is a point in $\Bbb R^2$), or discontinuous at $\emptyset$, or anything completely meaningless: any mathematical object that is not part of the set of inputs may be said to be a point of discontinuity, but you learn nothing.

Notice that you can also define a function $g:]1,2[\rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $g(x)=1/x$. Then $f$ and $g$ are *not* the same function, even though they are given by the same formula. And even $h:]1,2[\rightarrow \Bbb ]1/2,1[$ such that $h(x)=1/x$ is not the same thing as $g$. For example, $h$ is a bijection, whereas $g$ is not. Thus, the three components (input set, output set, relation) are all very important in the definition of a function.

Here, $0$ has a particular status only because when we see $]-\infty,0[\;\cup\;]0,+\infty[$, we see also the whole real line, and this additional number $0$. But the function is just not *defined* at $0$. This conveys more useful information to say that, than to say it's discontinuous.

---

Whatever we may decide about discontinuity where the function is not defined, there is a good news: there won't be another definition of continuity, for one good reason. The topological definition of continuity states that, given two topological spaces $A,B$, $f:A\rightarrow B$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(S)$ is open for all open subsets $S \subset B$.

This is the *standard* definition of continuity, and is equivalent in the real case with the definition which implies that $x\rightarrow 1/x$ is continuous. For example, for $a>0$, 
$$f^{-1}(]-\infty,-a[ \;\cup\; ]a,+\infty[)=]-1/a,0[\;\cup\;]0,1/a[$$
which is an open set.

---

Hence, I would say that these books I checked do the right thing: where the function is defined, we can argue about continuity or discontinuity. Where it's not defined, it's meaningless.

Comment: It's not "only your" opinion.

Comment: @DanielFischer Agreed, but I don't feel I'm in a position to enforce my opinion as the standard view on the subject. :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: but I am in position to do so.

Comment: The notion of an [isolated singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity) is widely used in (complex) analysis. It can make perfect sense to talk about properties of a function at particular points were it is not defined without having to admit talking about it wherever.

Comment: @quid Good point. The definition on Wikipedia states the function is then holomorphic on $D\backslash \{x_0\}$, but this idea is used more freely for [meromorphic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function). However, we are here talking about real analysis, where poles are usually not managed the same way, and functions are not as nice as holomorphic and meromorphic functions. Anyhow, this definition of continuity seems rather standard, I fear.

Comment: The point of my comment was to high-light that one of your assertions might need some qualification, namely this one: "It makes little sense to tell anything about a function where it's not defined." This also seems  false in a real analysis context, as it is very common (eg, some definitions of the derivative) to wonder if a function admits a limit at a  point where it is not defined (yet in a neighborhood of which it is defined). Further, the context is not only real analysis but also calculus, which is quite relevant to the question at hand, but I guess I have commented enough.

Comment: @quid Precisely, a *limit*. Continuity of a function is not *exactly* like computation of a limit (though it's very very close!), and it's not exactly like meromorphic function either. Actually, regarding limit, the french definition using $\epsilon-\delta$ is usually written with $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ instead of $0<|x-x_0|<\epsilon$. You may check that with this, existence of a limit is equivalent to continuity, but only where the function is defined, of course. But I guess you may find other examples where *non defined* is actually not that problematic (let's try computability theory?).

Comment: @quid You could even argue about $L^p$ functions :) Ok, it's cheating, they are *classes* of functions, and not really functions, when you deal with quotient space.

Comment: The point was not if it is or is not exactly the same but the veracity of your assertion. But I see you edited the post to accommodate the objection a bit, so maybe let us leave it there.

Answer (score 3):

No, I do not know that your function is discontinuous at zero. And indeed you don't understand why. Although your case is rather specific, I don't believe that a function is discontinuous outside its own domain of definition. Would you say that $x \mapsto \log x$ is discontinuous at $x=-1$? I definitely would not.

Your case is somehow special, since $0$ does not belong to the domain of definition, *but* it's an accumulation point. We might agree that a function is discontinuous at such points if it can't be defined at those points so that the resulting extension is continuous. This idea is often understood by calculus teachers, since it is considered kind of *natural*.
But if you move on to general topology, you'll discover that the concept itself of discontinuity is rather useless, since continuity is interesting when it occurs.

Coming back to your problem, it clear that no definition of $f(0)$ will turn $f$ into a continuous function (since $\lim_{x \to 0\pm} \frac{1}{x}=\pm\infty$). But I would not claim that $f$ is discontinuous *tout court*.

Comment: It is common to talk about continuity at a limit point of the domain of a function, and in that definition $1/x$ is discontinuous at $0$. Also $\log(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$ in that sense, but $x/x$ is continuous at $0$ in that sense.